# I am facing some trouble while rendering page

Tags: components, render, apex-code

I have a page of my website..
In that page I have a registration forms and videos and some text...
When I register in registration page and then come back to this page already registered, then registration box disappears..
It looks I have left my rendered tags set to hide the reg form if they are logged in.

Code I am using for that --

```
<c:HomePageRightReglanding rendered="{!ISPICKVAL($User.UserType,'Guest')}" />
```

`HomePageRightReglanding` my component name where I have form to display ...

Please help me out !!

Comment: Please provide a clear question.

Comment: You still haven't written a question. Just many statements. There is not even one question mark. I don't know what you want help with.
After a user registers, you say, the registration box disappears. Isn't that a good thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user to access a public site who user type is guest, but if you have registered, the user type will be change.

The user type is depended on user license.

> The category of user license. Each UserType is associated with one or more UserLicense records. Each UserLicense is associated with one or more profiles. In API version 10.0 and later, valid values include:
>
> - Standard: user license. This user type also includes Salesforce Platform and Salesforce Platform One user licenses. Label is Standard.
> - PowerPartner: PRM user whose access is limited because he or she is a partner and typically accesses the application through a partner portal. Label is Partner.
> - CSPLitePortal: user whose access is limited because he or she is an organization's customer and accesses the application through aCustomer Portal. Label is High Volume Portal.
> - CustomerSuccess: user whose access is limited because he or she is an organization's customer and accesses the application through a Customer Portal. Label is Customer Portal User.
> - PowerCustomerSuccess: user whose access is limited because he or she is an organization's customer and accesses the application through a Customer Portal. Label is Customer Portal Manager.
>   Users with this license type can view and edit data they directly own or data owned by or shared with users below them in the Customer Portal role hierarchy.